# standard libraries in using statements does not have any autocompletion is vs code 1.61.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, libraries

When I am trying to use any of the of standard System libs like System.Text there is no auto completion for my csharp code.  If I just try to use a stringbulider it all works but the vs code has no completion and seems to have no idea about the stringbuilder.  I have the omnisharp installed and normal completion for variables, types, etc works.

I am trying to transition from Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise for some projects and am wondering if VS Code just does not try to provide auto completion for csharp?

I also use python and have no problem with completion when using that with anaconda in the same vs code install.

Thanks